# How do you use getMapBoundaries with React Naitve Maps

Tags: react-native, google-maps, react-native-maps

Currently creating an application for a company. The user of the application is displayed on the map, and their pets are supposed to display on the map as well. In order to do that I need the boundaries of the map. I am using `react-native-maps` and it as a built function `getMapBoundaries`. When I use the function I have gotten the following errors

```
function getMapBoundaries does not exist
```

And the latest

```
Cannot set property map of undefined.
```

Here is what I have

```
const AppMapView = () => {
  
    const handleRegionChange = async region => {
      //I get an error for the statement below
      console.log(
        await this.map.getMapBoundaries()
          .then(response => {
            return response
          })
      )
    };
  
    handleRegionChange()
  
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MapView
          ref={ref => {
            this.map = ref;
          }}
        >
          <Marker
            coordinate={...}
          >
            <Image {...} />
          </Marker>
        </MapView>
      </View>
    )
};
  
  export default AppMapView;
```

A code example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is still searching for the answer, this works:

```
<MapView
    ref={mapView}
    onRegionChangeComplete={async (val) => {
       console.log(await mapRef.current.getMapBoundaries())
    }
>
    <Marker
       coordinate={...}
    >
    </Marker>
</MapView>
```

You can get it from current of the ref

Comment: this solution work for me, thank you
I don't know why not marked as answered?

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
mapRef = null;
onRegionChangeComplete = async () => {
  console.log("onRegionChangeComplete", await this.mapRef.getMapBoundaries());
};

 <MapView
    ref={(ref) => {
       this.mapRef = ref;
    }}
    onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}
    <Marker
       coordinate={...}
    >
    </Marker>
  </MapView>
```